# Why does the first assert work, but not the second?

Tags: watir-webdriver

I'm using Watir WebDriver with Firefox.

Here are two asserts for the same element. The first works, but not the second:

```
assert_match(/Please add user to GMT/, @browser.small(:class, "error").text)
assert_match(/Please add user to GMT/, @browser.div(:class, "eight mobile-three columns").small(:class, "error").text)
```

I need the second assert to work, because there are 8 error messages on the page, which are presented if the user does not populate 8 mandatory fields. All 8 errors have the identical HTML. So, I need to be able to step down from the parent.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="eight mobile-three columns">
  <a id="btnAddUserToGMT" class="success radius button expand error" onclick="AddUserToGMT();" data-reveal-id="addToGMT" href="#"> … </a>
  <small class="error" style="margin-top:0px;">

    Please add user to GMT

  </small>
</div>
```

Here is the error message:

```
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element, using {:class=>"error", :tag_name=>"small"}
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:490:in `assert_exists'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:85:in `text'
C:/Documents and Settings/Asserts_01.rb:22:in `testBasic'
```

The complaint for the second assert is:

```
unable to locate element, using {:class=>"error", :tag_name=>"small"}
```

And yet that same `using` was OK for the first assert.

Comment: If it helps, both assertions seem to work for me. Perhaps there is a different issue?

Comment: I copied the few lines of HTML into a file. I created a test with only the two assertions, and pointed the browser to the HTML file. Both assertions passed. I'm using RubyMine. In debug mode, when the real test fails, the file "testcase.rb" is opened in the RM editor. The following line is highlighted: `rescue Exception` then `@internal_data.interrupted` then `raise unless handle_exception($!)` Can you think of any troubleshooting I can do?

Comment: Are you sure the `<div class="eight mobile-three columns">` is unique - ie there are no other divs with the same set of classes? My thought is that there are multiple of these divs and the small element is not in the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

After discussion with the developer, it appears that by some unusual manipulation of automatically generated HTML, the text of the error message appears at its correct  location on the page. But the assertion must be based on a different tag, which is specified at some completely different position on the page.

For example, I was trying to assert on this code at the correct position:

```
<small class="error" style="margin-top:0px;">

  Gender is required

</small
```

Even unique xPath generated by FirePath failed to find this.

What I should have asserted on was a HIDDEN tag on a completely different part of the page.

```
<input id="errorMsgGenderID" name="errorMsgGenderID" type="hidden" value="Gender is required" />
```

There were several such tags for each mandatory field that was not populated, all bunched together on the same line. They were all "input" tags, which puzzled me.